# Add 'decimal-mark' thousands separators to a number

Tags: python, format, locale, number-formatting, digit-separator

How do I format `1000000` to `1.000.000` in Python? where the '.' is the decimal-mark thousands separator.

Comment: Please clearify your question.  Show some code, mention the data type of the object you want to print, give example output.

Comment: You cannot have more than one decimal point in a number. What is `1.000.000` supposed to mean? Do you mean commas?

Comment: @Noufal: in some locales, `.` is used instead of `,` to separate thousands.

Comment: Really? I wasn't aware of that. I don't think they'd be called "decimal points" in those locales though.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim, This called decimal mark and [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) explains which countries use different decimal mark styles.

Comment: Those interested in this issue may want to [look at my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345438/how-to-add-thousands-separator-to-a-number-that-has-been-converted-to-a-string-i/35957384#35957384) (to a similar question) which explores the limitations of using the `format()` solution and has code written to do the job.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

If you want to add a thousands separator, you can write:

```
>>> '{0:,}'.format(1000000)
'1,000,000'
```

But it only works in Python 2.7 and above.

See [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

In older versions, you can use [locale.format()](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.format):

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'en_AU.utf8'
>>> locale.format('%d', 1000000, 1)
'1,000,000'
```

the added benefit of using `locale.format()` is that it will use your locale's thousands separator, e.g.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf-8')
'de_DE.utf-8'
>>> locale.format('%d', 1000000, 1)
'1.000.000'
```

Comment: If you are working with currencies, you can also use the babel.numbers.format_currency helper.

Comment: For floats the syntax is `{:6,.2f}` where `6` is the field width and `2` is the precision. The placement of the comma tripped me up a bit.

Comment: You can check all installed locales with "$ locale -a", a default Ubuntu installation for instance will only have en_US so this is not a viable strategy.

Answer (score 22):

To format `1123000` as `1,123,000`, use the `format` function:

e.g.:

```
>>> format(1123000,',d')
'1,123,000'
```

See also:
https://docs.python.org/release/3.11.0/whatsnew/3.1.html#pep-378-format-specifier-for-thousands-separator

Comment: The language in your answer is somewhat confusing. Perhaps you could improve it?

Answer (score 21):

Just extending the answer a bit here :)

I needed to both have a thousandth separator and limit the precision of a floating point number.

This can be achieved by using the following format string:

```
> my_float = 123456789.123456789
> "{:0,.2f}".format(my_float)
'123,456,789.12'
```

This describes the `format()`-specifier's mini-language:

```
[[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
```

Source: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/#current-version-of-the-mini-language

Comment: what if he wanted to get the following output: `'123.456.789,12'` ?

Comment: @dot.Py he could set an appropriate locale `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf-8')` then use `("{:.%dn}" % (math.log10(my_float)+3)).format(my_float)` however the 'n' format string is the locale aware equivalent of 'g' rather than 'f' so the precision field gets messy.

Answer (score 6):

An idea

```
def itanum(x):
    return format(x,',d').replace(",",".")

>>> itanum(1000)
'1.000'
```

Comment: The simplest one and also perfectly suitable for my case! The replacement was also very precise.

Answer (score 2):

Strange that nobody mentioned a straightforward solution with regex:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=(\d{3})+$)', r'.', "12345673456456456"))
```

Gives the following output:

```
12.345.673.456.456.456
```

It also works if you want to separate the digits only before comma:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=(\d{3})+,)', r'.', "123456734,56456456")
```

gives:

```
123.456.734,56456456
```

the regex uses lookahead to check that the number of digits after a given position is divisible by 3.

---

Update 2021: Please use this for scripting only (i.e. only in situation where you can destroy the code after using it). When used in an application, this approach would constitute a [ReDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS).

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) can give you some more flexibility:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> num = "1000000"
>>> sep = "."
>>> places = 3
>>> args = [iter(num[::-1])] * places
>>> sep.join("".join(x) for x in zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=""))[::-1]
'1.000.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

Drawing on the answer by Mikel, I implemented his solution like this in my matplotlib plot. I figured some might find it helpful:

```
ax=plt.gca()
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, loc: locale.format('%d', x, 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

DIY solution

```
def format_number(n):
    result = ""
    for i, digit in enumerate(reversed(str(n))):
        if i != 0 and (i % 3) == 0:
            result += ","
        result += digit
    return result[::-1]
```

built-in solution

```
def format_number(n):
    return "{:,}".format(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's only a alternative answer.
You can use split operator in python and through some weird logic
Here's the code

```
i=1234567890
s=str(i)
str1=""
s1=[elm for elm in s]
if len(s1)%3==0:
    for i in range(0,len(s1)-3,3):
        str1+=s1[i]+s1[i+1]+s1[i+2]+"."
    str1+=s1[i]+s1[i+1]+s1[i+2]
else:
    rem=len(s1)%3
    for i in range(rem):
        str1+=s1[i]
    for i in range(rem,len(s1)-1,3):
        str1+="."+s1[i]+s1[i+1]+s1[i+2]

print str1
```

Output

```
1.234.567.890
```