# how to add thousands separator to a number that has been converted to a string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting

in my scenario (python 2.7), i have:

`str(var)`

where var is a variable that sometimes requires thousands separators eg 1,500 but as you can see has been converted to a string (for concatenation purposes).

i would like to be able to print out that variable as a string with thousands separators.

i have read solutions for adding formatting to a number eg:

```
>>> '{:20,.2}'.format(f)
'18,446,744,073,709,551,616.00'
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823189/1063287

but this seems to be applicable just for a number, not for a number that has been converted to a string.

thank you.

**edit:**  for more specific context, here is my implementation scenario:

```
print 'the cost = $' + str(var1) + '\n'
print 'the cost = $' + str(var2) + '\n'
```

and i have several 'vars'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use `str(var)` and concatenation, that is what `.format()` is *for*. Depending on the type of `var` pick one of:

```
'{:,}'.format(var)    # format an integer
'{:,.2f}'.format(var) # format a decimal or float
```

depending on the type of number you have.

```
>>> var = 12345678.123
>>> '{:,}'.format(int(var))  # ignore the `.123` part
'12,345,678'
>>> '{:,.2f}'.format(var)
'12,345,678.12'
```

Comment: thank you, my implementation is `print 'the cost = $' + str(var) + '\n'` so in this context how do i apply that logic? thank you.

Comment: No need to use `str(var)` at all, use `'the cost = ${:,.2f}\n'.format(var)` instead.

Comment: @user1063287: your situation is much simpler, in fact. Do not use string concatenation if string formatting can be used instead.

Comment: thank you very much, i will use your suggestions, i am getting a large 'indentation' or 'space' before the outputted value when using `print 'the cost = $' + '{:20,}'.format(int(var)) + '\n'`

Comment: @user1063287: You may want to read the [formatting syntax spec](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax); updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming very late to this question which I found while looking for a solution for the same thing.

Using the `,` notation with `format()` can work very well but poses some problems because unfortunately the `,` notation can not be applied to strings. So if you are starting with text representations of numbers then you have to convert them to integers or floats before calling `format()`. The `format()` code rapidly becomes quite complex if you need to handle both integers and floats with varying levels of precision which need to be preserved. To handle such a situation I ended up writing my own code instead of using `format()`. It uses the most widely used thousands separator (`,`) and decimal mark (`.`) but it could clearly be very quickly modified to work with the notation of other locales or used to create a solution which works for all locales.

```py
def separate_thousands_with_delimiter(num_str):
    """
    Returns a modified version of "num_str" with thousand separators added.
    e.g. "1000000" --> "1,000,000", "1234567.1234567" --> "1,234,567.1234567".
    Numbers which require no thousand separators will be returned unchanged.
    e.g. "123" --> "123", "0.12345" --> "0.12345", ".12345" --> ".12345".
    Signed numbers (a + or - prefix) will be returned with the sign intact.
    e.g. "-12345" --> "-12,345", "+123" --> "+123", "-0.1234" --> "-0.1234".
    """

    decimal_mark = "."
    thousands_delimiter = ","

    sign = ""
    fraction = ""

    # If num_str is signed, store the sign and remove it.
    if num_str[0] == "+" or num_str[0] == "-":
        sign = num_str[0]
        num_str = num_str[1:]

    # If num_str has a decimal mark, store the fraction and remove it.
    # Note that find() will return -1 if the substring is not found.
    dec_mark_pos = num_str.find(decimal_mark)
    if dec_mark_pos >= 0:
        fraction = num_str[dec_mark_pos:]
        num_str = num_str[:dec_mark_pos]

    # Work backwards through num_str inserting a separator after every 3rd digit.
    i = len(num_str) - 3
    while i > 0:
        num_str = num_str[:i] + thousands_delimiter + num_str[i:]
        i -= 3

    # Build and return the final string.
    return sign + num_str + fraction


# Test with:

test_nums = ["1", "10", "100", "1000", "10000", "100000", "1000000",
             "-1", "+10", "-100", "+1000", "-10000", "+100000", "-1000000",
             "1.0", "10.0", "100.0", "1000.0", "10000.0", "100000.0",
             "1000000.0", "1.123456", "10.123456", "100.123456", "1000.123456",
             "10000.123456", "100000.123456", "1000000.123456", "+1.123456",
             "-10.123456", "+100.123456", "-1000.123456", "+10000.123456",
             "-100000.123456", "+1000000.123456", "1234567890123456789",
             "1234567890123456789.1", "-1234567890123456789.1",
             "1234567890123456789.123456789", "0.1", "0.12", "0.123", "0.1234",
             "-0.1", "+0.12", "-0.123", "+0.1234", ".1", ".12", ".123",
             ".1234", "-.1", "+.12", "-.123", "+.1234"]

for num in test_nums:
    print("%s --> %s" % (num, separate_thousands_with_delimiter(num)))


# Beginners should note that an integer or float can be converted to a string
# very easily by simply using: str(int_or_float)

test_int = 1000000
test_int_str = str(test_int)
print("%d --> %s" % (test_int, separate_thousands_with_delimiter(test_int_str)))

test_float = 1000000.1234567
test_float_str = str(test_float)
print("%f --> %s" % (test_float, separate_thousands_with_delimiter(test_float_str)))
```

Hope this helps. :)