# How do I right align monetary values with the "$" next to each number, not just at the margin?

Tags: python, formatting, python-3.4

I am trying to right align some monetary values to look like this:

```
John Smith         $3,500
Jane Doe             $200
Jack Johnson         $700
```

But I am getting this:

```
John Smith         $3500
Jane Doe           $ 200
Jack Johnson       $ 700.
```

My code for the output looks like this:

```
for (name, amount) in cursor:
    print("{}".format(name)+ "\t\t\t" + "${:>5,.0f}".format( amount))
```

I would also like to put a comma separator for numbers in the thousands. I know I've seen the formatting for this before, but I am having trouble finding it again.

Comment: I don't think there's a built in directive for that, so you might have to figure out how long the number is for yourself and write your own function to print it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513615/add-thousands-separators-to-a-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, remove the spaces at both sides of the number string.

```
for (name, amount) in cursor: 
    print("{}".format(name)+ "\t\t\t" + "{:>5}".format("$"+ "{:.0f}".format(amount).strip()))
```

Comment: I tried using the strip method earlier, but it just moves the numbers closer to the '$'.

Comment: I must have missed something because it works perfect now.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
for (name,amount) in cursor:
     print("{}".format(name) + "\t\t\t"  +  "${}".format(int(amount)))
```

Comment: That solves the $ being next to the number problem, but I don't need the decimals after the numbers.

Comment: Do you realize that `'{}'.format(name)` is kind of pointless? And `'${}'.format(int(amount))` doesn't right-align anything - and the `int()` call is unnecessary? This isn't even an attempt at solving the problem.