# How can I change the (locale) thousands separator in Python to Arabic Unicode separator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, number-formatting, arabic, digit-separator

I'd like to change the thousands separator such that `{:,}.format(1234)` in Python uses a different character. The separator should be `'\u066c'`.

How can I set this without affecting any other locals settings?

EDIT: Any other suggestion for a unimposing separator viable in a fixed with font is welcome!

Comment: See [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513615/add-decimal-mark-thousands-separators-to-a-number) and [PEP 378 - Format Specifier for Thousands Separator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your options are to either take the `,` formatted output and replace the commas, switch locales and use the `'n'` number format (which will format the number based on the current locale), or use a third party library like [babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/). The latter gives you full locale control over [number formatting](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/numbers.html#numbers), for example, provided there is a locale that uses U+066C as the thousands separator.

With the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format), the first option is quite straight-forward really:

```
>>> format(1234, ',').replace(',', '\u066c')
'1٬234'
```

I have yet to find a locale that directly would use `\u066c` for *Western* Arabic numerals however; U+066C is commonly used only with Eastern Arabic numerals instead. Babel doesn't include any such locale data, at least.

You can pass any babel `Locale` object in to the [`babel.numbers.format_number()` function](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html#babel.numbers.format_number), so if you need a custom separator you can clone an existing locale and set the `Locale.number_symbols['group']` value:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from babel import Locale

us_locale = Locale('en', 'US')
base_locale.number_symbols   # ensure instance has been populated
altered_locale = deepcopy(us_locale)
altered_locale.number_symbols['group'] = '\u066c'
```

Note that you have to access an attribute (or the `._data` property) to trigger loading the locale configuration, before copying. Otherwise, the data between the original (source) locale and the altered locale will be shared (so the `us_locale` object in my snippet above would have the same number separator.

Using the `altered_locale` object now results in the expected output:

```
>>> from babel.numbers import format_number
>>> format_number(1234, locale=altered_locale)
'1٬234'
```

Comment: Regarding the cloning of the `Locale`, you need to access one of the `Locale`'s properties before deep copying, otherwise you will overwrite the base locale. `base_locale = Locale("en", "US")` then just acces a property `base_locale.number_symbols`, this loads the data, and then copy `altered_locale = deepcopy(base_locale)` then you can alter the locale withouth influencing any other locales.

Comment: Careful! I downvoted this answer because the deepcopy operation does not work as expected. See Viliers's comment just above that explains the problem

Comment: @VilliersStraus ah, indeed, I've updated my answer to avoid that issue.

Comment: @EdwardGaere: I've fixed that issue now.

Answer (score 3):

Taking Martijn's excellent answer further for use in Django, on how to override a locale in a Django template.

File `myapp/templatetags/extra.py`

```
from django import template
from django.utils.translation import get_language
from copy import deepcopy
from babel import Locale
from babel.numbers import format_number

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def currency(value):
    lang = get_language()
    locale = deepcopy(Locale(lang))
    if lang == 'ru':  # for example if russian
        locale.number_symbols['group'] = '.'
    return format_number(value, locale=locale)
```

In template:

```
{% load extra %}
{{ price|currency }}
```