# Converting scientific notation in Series to commas and thousands separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Series with Name as the index and a number in scientific notation such as 3.176154e+08. How can I convert this number to 317,615,384.61538464 with a thousands separator? I tried:

format(s, ',')

But it returns TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.**format**
There are no NaNs in the data.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @raninjan Thank you for the help! That works perfectly. I saw that other thread but didn't realize I needed to apply the lambda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `'{:,}'.format(s)` as described [in response to another similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5513747/1936114). Using your example:

```
s = pd.Series([3.176154e+08,3.176154e+08],name='Name') 
s.apply(lambda x: '{:,}'.format(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

`SeriesName.map('{:,}'.format)`