# Python number formatting

Tags: python, numbers, format

I have an issue with formatting number output in Python. I found quite some examples how to do it with `.format()`, but I can not figure it out how to set it up to my desired output.

I would like to have "." as thousand separator and "," as decimal (e.g. 7.654,32). If I want to do it vice-versa, I would use e.g. `print("{0:,.2f}".format(7654.321))`, but I can not find the opposite. If nothing else, I could use `replace()`, but would prefer an elegant solution, as I would use that further with `Jinja2` in my html template.

Thank you and best regards,

Bostjan

Comment: Have you tried setting the `locale` as used here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5513747/4636715

Comment: Hello vahdet. Thanks for your answer. I have been playing with locale as well, but I would prefer to code it in a single line, as I am using this in html code with Jinja2 - e.g.{{ "{0:,}".format(type.1) }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html) for many types of utilities. For your case I think `format_number` and `format_decimal` is ideal. First you can install `Babel` with `pip install Babel`. And formatting your number you can use `de_DE` as locale.

```
from babel.numbers import format_number

formatted_number = format_number(7654.321, locale='de_DE')
print(formatted_number)
>>> 7.654,321
```

Comment: Hello Abdull, thank you for answer. This indeed works on single number. I run into issue than that I am using pandas df to populate html template via Jinja2 (using df.as_matrix()). I wonder if there is any simple solution, where you specify format of output e.g. "{:,.2f}".format()?

Comment: The other simple solution might be replacing. Single line and simple without any dependency `formatted_number = "{:,.2f}".format(7654.321).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", ".")`.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for, thank you very much for this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any other packages and still one-liner

```
num = 7654.321
format(int(num), ",d").replace(",",".") + "," + "{0:,.2f}".format(num-int(num))[2:]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for feedback. This (along with Abdull's response) work as well, thank you for that.