# PYTHON how I separate numbers by dots every three steps?

Tags: python

Example

```
test = "123456789123"
```

I tried

```
test = "1234567"

print(".".join(test))
```

result

```
1.2.3.4.5.6.7
```

but I would like this

result

```
123.456.789.123
```

Comment: I find the proposed duplicate strange. It seems as if the op is asking about formatting numbers with thousands separator, not about slicing lists in chunks.

Comment: The current link to duplicate redirects to some codon-splitting molecular biologist answer. If you are more interested in formatting numbers with thousands-separator, take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513615/add-decimal-mark-thousands-separators-to-a-number/49868510#49868510).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very naive solution without list comprehension:

```
test = '123456789123'
result = ''

while test:
    result += test[:3]
    if len(test) > 3:
        result += '.'
    test = test[3:]

print(result)
```

Comment: cool, and something like this:
result 123.456.789-123

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple regex solution:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=(\d{3})+$)', r'.', "12345673456456456"))
```

It produces the following output:

```
12.345.673.456.456.456
```

the regex uses lookahead to check that the number of digits after a given position is divisible by 3.

Comment: May the downvoter enlighten us all with the only correct solution? If even the accepted answer got two downvotes, there must be a better way, I assume... I actually find solving the problem in a single line by passing two constants and the input string to a standard library method a rather efficient solution, so I'd really appreciate an explanation why this is worth a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really need a dot, you can simply use:

```
formated_number = "{:,}".format(value)
```

And if you really want those dots:

```
formated_number.replace(',','.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the characters as a list and track where you are with a counter:

```
s = "123456789123"
output = []
count = 0
for c in list(s):
  count += 1
  if count == 4:
    output.append(".")
    count = 0
    continue
  else:
    output.append(c)

result = ''.join(output)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward implementation:

```
test = "1234567891234431222334442234ee3432"
testJoined = ""

for i in range(0,len(test),3):
    testJoined += test[i:i+3] + "."

print(testJoined[0:-1])
```

test1:

```
"1234567891234431222334442234ee3432"
```

result1:

```
123.456.789.123.443.122.233.444.223.4ee.343.2
```

test2:

```
"1234567891234431222334442234ee34aa32"
```

result2:

```
123.456.789.123.443.122.233.444.223.4ee.34a.a32
```