# How to use .format() specifiers such as ,.2f while trying to format variables in?

Tags: python-3.x, string, format

How do I format a number to have a thousands separator and round to two decimals while trying to format a variable in?
For example

```
print('{} earns {} a year".format(name, earnings ':,.2f')
```

doesn't seem to work. How do I add in both variables but format my number value?

Comment: Has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32777579/5223223).

Comment: While reading carefully the documentation (or that answer) would resolve the question, this error/mistake/misconception is oddly specific that it's virtually impossible to come up in a [search engine)] search.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the format inside the curly brackets.

Full example here: https://thepythonguru.com/python-string-formatting/

`"Floating point {0:.2f}".format(345.7916732)`

Expected output:

`>>> Floating point 345.79`

Likewise `"Floating point pi = {0:.3f}, with {1:d} digit precision".format(math.pi, 3)`

Expected output:

`>>> Floating point pi = 3.142, with 3 digit precision`