# Use a period (.) to separate thousands in the highchart tooltip

Tags: javascript, python, highcharts

I want to use a period (.) to separate thousands in the highchart tooltip like `'lang': { 'thousandsSep': '.' }` but I was unsuccessful.

This sentence expresses frustration with trying different methods to use a period for thousands separation in a Highcharts tooltip but experiencing issues, as shown in the provided example.

```py
from highcharts_core.chart import Chart
as_dict = {
    'chart': {
        'type': 'column',
        'style': {
            "fontSize": "1.7rem",
            'fontFamily': 'Helvetica'
        },
        'height': 600
    },
    'title': {
        'text': 'Major trophies for some English teams',
        'align': 'center'
    },
    'xAxis': {
        'categories': df_chart_1.index.to_list(),
        'lineColor': 'while'
    },
    'yAxis': [{
        'title': {
            'text': 'Count trophies'
        },
        'stackLabels': {
            'enabled': True
        },
        'stackLabels': {
        'enabled': False  # Hiển thị số tổng
        }
    },{
        'min': -3,
        'title': {
            'text': 'Additional Data'
        },
        'labels': {
            'format': '{value}%',
        },
        'opposite': True
    }],
    'legend': {
        'align': 'center',
        'layout': 'horizontal',
        'verticalAlign': 'bottom',
        'backgroundColor': 'white',
        'borderColor': '#CCC',
        'borderWidth': 1,
        'shadow': False,
    },
    'tooltip': {
        'shared': False,  # Tắt chia sẻ tooltip giữa các series,
        'hideDelay':10
    },
    'plotOptions': {
        'column': {
            'stacking': 'normal',
            'dataLabels': {
                'enabled': False,
                'formatter': "function() { return this.y.toFixed(2); }"
            },
            'tooltip': {
                'headerFormat': '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                'pointFormat': '{series.name}: {point.y:,.2f} ({point.percentage:.1f}%)<br/>',
                'usehtml': True
            }
        },
        'spline': {
            'dataLabels': {
                'enabled': True,
                'formatter': "function() { return this.y.toFixed(2); }" 
            },
            'tooltip': {
                'headerFormat': '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                'pointFormat': '{series.name}: {point.y:,.2f}<br/>',
            }
        },
        'series': {
            'stickyTracking': False
        }
    },
    'series': [{
        'name': 'Nợ nhóm 2',
        'data': df_chart_1[748].to_list(),
        'color':'#C6DBD0',
        'visible': False
    }, {
        'name': 'Nợ nhóm 3',
        'data': df_chart_1[749].to_list(),
        'color':'#C6DBD0'
    }, {
        'name': 'Nợ nhóm 4',
        'data': df_chart_1[750].to_list(),
        'color':'#9ECBED'
    }, {
        'name': 'Nợ nhóm 5',
        'data': df_chart_1[751].to_list(),
        'color':'#3C97DA'
    }, {
        'type': 'spline',
        'yAxis': 1,
        'name': 'Tỷ lệ nợ xấu',
        'data': df_chart_1['Tỷ lệ nợ xấu'].to_list(),
    }],
    'lang': {
        'thousandsSep': '\u002C'
    },
}


chart = Chart(options = as_dict)
chart.display()
```

`point.y:,.2f` is not working as well

```
'pointFormat': '{series.name}: {point.y:,.2f} ({point.percentage:.1f}%)<br/>'
```

It still uses a space to separate thousands, not the period (.) as intended.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5513747/6394617)?

Answer (score 0):

As the API says:

*The language object is global and it can't be set on each chart initialization. Instead, use `Highcharts.setOptions` to set it before any chart is initialized.*

```
 Highcharts.setOptions({
   lang: {
     thousandsSep: '.'
   }
 })

 Highcharts.chart('container', {
   series: [{
     data: [7777, 8888, 9999]
   }]
 });
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xq2jhbgc/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang

Comment: But I don't know how to use in python highchart

Answer (score 0):

*FULL DISCLOSURE: I'm the primary author of Highcharts for Python.*

Unfortunately, setting the Highcharts JS separator in Highcharts for Python is more complicated than it should be (though it is slated to be refactored in a future version).

Setting the thousands separator relies on the `global_options.language.Language` and `global_options.shared_options.SharedOptions` classes.

To configure the thousand separator, you will want to create a `Language` instance and a `SharedOptions` instance by calling:

```
from highcharts_core.global_options.language import Language
from highcharts_core.global_options.shared_options import SharedOptions

my_language_instance = Language(thousands_separator = '.')
my_global_options = SharedOptions(language = my_language_instance)
```

This code snippet configures a set of shared options where you have set your language configuration, featuring your thousands separator. When the `SharedOptions` instance is serialized to a JS literal using the `my_global_options.to_js_literal()` method, it will create the `Highcharts.setOptions(...)` JavaScript instruction.

Next, how you use this depends a little bit on the environment / context for where you want your charts to render.

**Using Jupyter Notebook**
If you want your chart to render within Jupyter notebook, you can pass `my_global_options` to the chart's `.display()` method like so (assuming your chart is configured in `my_chart`):

```
my_chart.display(global_options = my_global_options)
```

**Generating Raw JavaScript**
If you are generating raw JavaScript, when you serialize shared options to JS literal they take the form of the `Highcharts.setOptions()` JS instructions:

```
my_global_options.to_js_literal()
```

will produce the JS code:

```
Highcharts.setOptions(
  lang: {
    thousandsSep: '.'
  }
);
```

How you deliver this JS code to your front-end is a different question, which depends on how you are integrating your Python code with your front-end. For example, you can incorporate the Python call into your Flask templates, your Django layouts, as the output of a FastAPI API call, or saved to a JS file that your front-end can load as a dependency. The options here are too broad to outline here, I'm afraid.

But the important part that hopefully answers your question is the description above.